# Removing GRUB from windows system after uninstalling Ubuntu from Windows 7

Tags: uninstall

I have installed Ubuntu alongside Windows 7 (no separate partitions, I selected inside windows option).

I want to uninstall Ubuntu but last time I tried it and the Ubuntu is released but the GRUB remains. How do I remove GRUB?

Answer (score 28):

You need `Windows 7` installation disk, boot it, choose **repair option** when you are asked to menu.

It will check automatically for start up problems. Let it check it.

- It will not find any problem with start up.
- It will allow to choose options. Choose `command prompt`.
- In `cmd` you have to type just two following commands and grub will be removed.

  ```
  bootrec /fixmbr  
  bootrec /fixboot
  ```

Close cmd and restart your machine.

Answer (score 10):

Here's how.

- Download and burn the [Super Grub Disk ISO](http://download.berlios.de/supergrub/super_grub_disk_0.9799.iso) to a CD.
- Boot from it.
- Select the `Choose Language & HELP  :-))` entry.
- Select the English entry.
- Select the `Windows` entry.
- Select the `Fix Boot of Windows` entry.
- Reboot once the process is complete.

**No more Grub!** :)

Comment: Better get Rescatux from here http://www.supergrubdisk.org/category/download/rescatuxdownloads/rescatux-stable/ View: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kpJoNHjiOOs

Comment: The link in this answer is broken.

Comment: Rescatux is now the way to go, or Boot-Repair.. This answer was on point when it was written, three and a half years ago. :)

Answer (score 3):

- Put windows 7 disk and boot from it.
- Choose to repair windows now.
- It will ask to repair, select yes.  After restart if grub is still there, follow above    step.
- Select windows partition found by the recovery manager and click `Next`
- Now choose startup repair.

This internally uses command `fixboot` and `fixmbr`. You can google for more details.