# remove grub when there is no Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, grub2, windows-7

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my partitioned hard disc:

```
/dev/sda
/dev/sda1   ntfs   Windows
/dev/sda2   ntfs   Backup Disk
/dev/sda3   ext4   Ubuntu 12.04
```

I can boot from Ubuntu and Windows via Grub. Now, I decided to remove the Ubuntu since I'm always stuck with getting the driver to work properly on my Radeon HD 7770 (always causing boot failure). I cannot find ways to uninstall it (there is an option in the installer where **Remove Ubuntu 12.04 and reinstall it** but that does suits), so I decided to delete the Ubuntu partition in `/dev/sda3` thinking it would solve the problem.

However, when I restarted my desktop the GRUB (purple background) still shows the *Ubuntu, Memory Test, Windows (loader)*. I want to remove this so that my desktop will boot directly from Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You can the steps from this link:
[Removing GRUB from windows system after uninstalling Ubuntu from Windows 7](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151253/removing-grub-from-windows-system-after-uninstalling-from-withing-windows)
You can also see   http://www.sevenforums.com/installation-setup/62209-remove-grub-restore-windows-7-a.html
You can create a system repair disc in windows 7.Use that disc to boot.
You can also launch recovery options by pressing F8 repeatedly before the windows boot logo appears.

Comment: Thanks, too bad I don't have the Windows 7 DVD with me here.