# Help with recoverinig windows Boot manager with kernel-less grub?

Tags: boot, grub2, grubrescue

I installed a dual boot Ubuntu with windows 8 a while ago on my sisters computer, but I didn't need Ubuntu anymore. So I followed instructions on how to remove Ubuntu, grub, and restore windows boot manager. But, I don't get windows. I get a CMD grub and that's it. I am very frustrated and upset because the computer is useless now. Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Removing GRUB from windows system after uninstalling Ubuntu from Windows 7](http://askubuntu.com/questions/151253/removing-grub-from-windows-system-after-uninstalling-ubuntu-from-windows-7)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on) (answers there address various ways of doing this)

Answer (score 0):

Use windows 8 CD or live USB. Boot into CD/USB and select 'REPAIR' windows. Select the repair with Command prompt(CMD).

Type the below commands to get the windows boot loader to normal.

```
Bootrec/fixmbr
Bootrec/fixboot
```

After it gives successful message restart.