# Grub freeze, Live-USB freezing, BIOS-Setup freezing, Windows (dualboot) working fine

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows, 15.10

I'm using a Lenovo Y50-70.

Grub, Linux, Live-USBs and the BIOS-Setup (insydeh20) (no CD-Drive, can't test that) are freezing after a few seconds.

If I'm fast enough for selecting Windows in Grub, it's booting up fine.

There is also no other PC around I could put that drive in.

.

I have absolutely no idea what I'm supposed to do from here. It happened after an Ubuntu-Installation that just froze at the very end (restart-prompt).

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Windows? Do you use Bios or Uefi.

There may be easier solutions but a reinstall should work for you.

Start Windows.

Right click on My Computer or This PC

Select manage.

Choose Disk Management.

Right click on the Ubuntu partition and select delete.

Make sure you don't choose any other partition.

Plug in the USB and format it as FAT32.

Check the md5 checksum of the iso you downloaded.

Make a bootable USB again with the iso.

Try reinstalling Ubuntu with the new USB drive.

While installing, choose Ubuntu partition preferably as ext4.

To remove grub after removing Ubuntu -->

Boot with a windows disc or USB.

Go to repair this computer.

Choose Command prompt.

Run this command

> bootrec /fixmbr

Reboot.

Comment: Windows 10. The BIOS is UEFI. Noticed that Windows will only startup if it's fast enough, too. When booting into some recovery modes, it will freeze. Installed Ubuntu exactly as you told me. Remade the Live-USB, no result.

Comment: @AndreasS. Try another EFI boot manager if grub does not work for you.

Comment: The problem is already, that I can't get rid of it. [That](http://askubuntu.com/questions/151253/removing-grub-from-windows-system-after-uninstalling-ubuntu-from-windows-7) didn't work. At least not from the Windows 10 recovery cmd.

Comment: Did so. Grub is still there. I have a feeling that something is horribly broken.

Comment: @AndreasS. Check edited answer

Comment: Tried it another time. No effect. bootrec/rebuildbcd also doesn't detect any Windows Installations (depends on how this thing work for having any significance, I guess).

Comment: Going to try if I can do a firmware upgrade, afterwards I'm wiping to harddrive and start praying. Going to report later if it worked. If you're not hearing from me again I probably killed it entirely....

Comment: Ok, I'm where I started from. At first there was no change, still BIOS freezes but after some time it just stopped freezing...??? Well, now I'm still dealing with Ubuntu freezing during install. I noticed, that it does freeze for sure if I stop making any inputs. I'm next to giving up. I'll probably just install it into VirtualBox and call it a day.

Comment: @AndreasS. Try reinstalling windows altogether. It would definitely wipe out grub.